# tkinter askinteger produces errors when used in a button function

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, dialog

I am trying to get a askinteger dialog box to open on a button click in python, and then store the value in a variable. Here is my Code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.simpledialog import askinteger

class test:
    def __init__(self, win):
        self.value = 0
        self.button = Button(win, text='Enter Integer', command=self.getint)
        self.button.place(x=150, y=150)
        
        self.valbutton = Button(win, text='Value', command=self.showvalue)
        self.valbutton.place(x=150, y=250)
    
    def getint(self):
        self.value = askinteger('Integer','Enter Integer')
        
    def showvalue(self):
        print(self.value)
        
window=Tk()
mywin=test(window)
window.title=('Test')
window.geometry('300x300+10+10')
window.mainloop()
```

I then get the following errors:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "testaskint.py", line 14, in getint
    self.value = askinteger('Integer','Enter Integer')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/tkinter/simpledialog.py", line 354, in askinteger
    d = _QueryInteger(title, prompt, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/tkinter/simpledialog.py", line 282, in __init__
    Dialog.__init__(self, parent, title)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/tkinter/simpledialog.py", line 136, in __init__
    Toplevel.__init__(self, master)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2624, in __init__
    self.title(root.title())
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Any help resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are trying to assign a string ('Test') as a callable function to `window.title`. Hence, you get the error: `'str' object is not callable`. Replace `window.title=('Test')` with `window.title('Test')`. That should solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks. I feel like such an idiot for missing that.